# What are the different tiers of gear mods?

Tags: the-division

I've noticed that the Gear Mods with stat boosts all have varying levels of stat bonus.

The main chunk of them I have I bought from the Base of Operations Phoenix credits vendor (I forget the official title of this npc) as blueprints and crafted. These all seem to be lv30 items with bonuses around 120.

I also have one 'Prototype Electronics Mod' which has a bonus closer to 130.

Are there different tiers of gear mods, or do they just follow standard item levels in that higher level gear mods are named differently?

- Gear Mod lv30 stat 120ish
- Prototype Mod lv31 stat 130ish

Is there a tier above and below these, and if so how are they named?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The highest gear mod level I've seen is level 30 *and* power level 32 (in the same item). Higher the power level, higher the stats/bonuses.
The power level doesn't change the itens name, the name describes what kind of mod it is, actually there are three types:

1. **Stat bonuses mods:** these only add stats, no bonuses
2. **Performance mods:** doesn't add stats, only bonuses like +130 armor, + 1.5% crit chance, etc.
3. **Mods that boosts stats and has a bonus**

PS: I'm don't remember the names of *1.* and *3.*

Comment: So if the item level doesn't affect the name, are they just random?

Comment: @David Yell the item name is related to it's purpose, to describe if it affect only stats, or only bonus, or both.

Comment: *"only add stats, no bonuses"* — I don't think I ever seen one (at least on level 30). Only stat + 1 bonus or 2 bonuses

Answer (score -2):

On [this reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/42mom0/crafting_gear_and_gear_mods_collage/) there is an image that shows all the available gear mods!

<sup>Click on the image below to view the higher-resolution, original image.</sup>
[image]

Comment: Also, on closer look, this does not answer the question being asked, at all. Asker is asking about the different tiers marked by the prefix, where as you are simply showing the *possible modifiers*, and not the differance between prefix.

Comment: The article opens with "Just a few more days and the beta starts" I'm sure we can find more up to date information. Plus this doesn't even touch on how item level effects the gear mod stat bonus.